# Automation of SSL Certificate generation using Digicert REST api

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, csr, certificate-authority

We have a requirement of automating the process of certificate generation and raising a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) with a CA (Digicert in our case) and there by receiving a signed certificate.

Now Digicert has a set of REST apis to achieve the same [Digicert Api](http://www.digicert.com/rest-api.htm).

The overall steps in automating the process will be like

1. Generating a private key (using Bouncy Castle api)
2. Raise a CSR with Digicert using their api. This should be at the same time creating the private key. The CSR would include the public key. More info  on a CSR is mentioned [here](http://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html)
3. Use  the API to fetch the signed certificate.

My question is , has anyone done something similar like this before? What are the few issues that might crop up that i should know of.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Answering this obsolete question for posterity:

Digicert's [current CertCentral offering](https://www.digicert.com/solutions/security-solutions-for-automation) includes what they call Automation, which wraps up the ACME APIs in a very nice GUI. It relies on another ACME package to do its work -- on Windows targets, that package is `win-acme` -- to generate CSRs, install certs in the proper cert repository for that machine, etc. But the Automation Agent handles all the communication with Digicert, reporting its installed certs and bindings over the REST API, invoking `win-acme` to do the CSR submission, etc. And the server-side web UI makes requesting, renewing or reissuing certs practically turnkey.  End of sales pitch.

(There are plenty of screenshots at that link so I won't add any more.)